# Deploying asp.net core rc2 web app on IIS8 / Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I've managed to publish my app and deploy it to my server, but I can't seem to make it run via IIS. I'm getting error `0x8007007b Cannot read configuration file`.

My web.config, after publishing, looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\RetailGuardian.Web.exe" arguments="" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Edit:** In case the problem is down to the app or how I've published it:

- The app targets `net452`
- There's a postpublish script: `dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%`
- I publish the app using `dotnet publish ./src/RetailGuardian.Web/ --framework net452 --runtime win7-x64 -c Release`
- This creates a series of outputs at `./src/RetailGuardian.Web/bin`
- To deploy, I'm coping `./src/RetailGuardian.Web/bin/Release/net452/win7-x64/publish` onto my server and setting this as the physical path in IIS. Setting the .NET CLR version for the app pool to 'No managed code'

Unfortunately I can't even get any log output as logging fails due to being unable to read the configuration file :(

Comment: Did you install Asp.NET Core module on the target server? You can download the bundle here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download. Use "Windows (Server Hosting)" when installing in production environment.

Comment: Yeah I installed it. I also made sure the dependencies were all installed

Comment: Are you sure IIS has permissions to access/read your web.config file? I would also check event log for some interesting events.

Comment: I'm sure IIS has permission to access, I've checked that web.config against several others on that server for older web apps that I know are working and seem to have the same access rights. Another issue mentioned that the group IIS_IUSRS may be needed which I added but that didn't make any difference. I've had a look at the event logs and didn't see anything of interest immediately but I'll keep digging

Comment: Nope there's nothing helpful in the event viewer. I added an overview of how I'm getting from source -> server, mind taking a look at that to see if anything looks wrong?

Comment: I just tried the 'Test Settings...' button on the sites 'Basic Settings' section in IIS and got the following, which looks like it supports your suggestion that IIS doesn't have permission:

Comment: `The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.`

Comment: Ok, I gave "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" the required permissions for the web.config but the test still failed. I then set the 'Connect As...' user to myself and it passes, but... the same error still shows when I try to access the site :(